# I want to upload file in angular 4 and I cannot append file to Formdata

Tags: angular, laravel-5.4

### this is my upload function

and when i console log the formData no data in it

```
let fileList: FileList = event.target.files;
    if(fileList.length > 0) {
      let file: File = fileList[0];
      let formData:FormData = new FormData();
      formData.append('photo',file);

      let currentUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser'));
      let headers = new Headers();
      headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');
      headers.append('Authorization','Bearer' + currentUser);

      let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
      this.http.post(this.apiUrl + 'v1/createEmp', formData, options)
          .map(res => res.json())
          // .catch(error => Observable.throw(error))
          .subscribe(
              data => console.log(data),
              error => console.log(error)
          );
    }
```

### this is my html

`<input type="file" (change)="fileUpload($event)" placeholder="Upload file" accept=".jpg,.png">`

Answer (score 0):

Whats seems to be a problem? `FormData` is configured properly. Please note that you won't see file in DevTools in network tab as far as I remember it will be in `base64` repesntation of this file. Last thing is I think that setting `Content-Type` to headers is neccessary to properly process request on the server side, so you should add `headers.append('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data')`

Comment: but the case is file not appended to formData.. so back end received a empty object.use consloe log for formData its is empty

Comment: Is it completly empty like `{}` or it contains something? Because simply console log `FormData` wouldn't show you files. Try `formData.entries()` and then iterate through it and log it.

Comment: there is no formData.entries()  method

Comment: Then you overwrite it somewhere. [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/entries). Are you using this after you assign file to formData? look at this sample [code](https://paste.ofcode.org/SjJUV7qy4xEMBXZbNHZgcM)

Comment: it keep me there is no ` entries() ` method

Comment: Are you using safari or IE :D? (it is not implement on theese vendors). Try to append `header` that i wrote above, and in laravel make sure that you reference to `'photo' `

Comment: Can you modify question or upload somewhere your actual code (angular and laravel. only the upload part and receive the request) and are you using safari or IE?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157051/discussion-between-ipula-and-szarik).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot log formData object to get its content. First, send the file and see from the server.

Comment: i tried object came..but laravel did not recognized as a file